# How to make a matrix with \llparenthesis and \rrparenthesis?

Tags: brackets

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{ stmaryrd }
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
$\left\llparenthesis\!\!\!\left\llparenthesis\!
\begin{matrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{matrix}
\!\right\rrparenthesis\!\!\!\right\rrparenthesis
$
\end{document}
```

which provides the following:

[image]

How do I change the code to provide both brackets as long as the numbers 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: the characters are not extendable and your example produces the error `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).`  so no usable output. This is a feature of the font so not changable from tex.

Comment: why the negative spacing and overprinting?

Comment: How do I correct the document to get rid of that error?

Comment: you can only apply `\left` and `\right` to specified delimiter characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font does not supply extensable `⦇` so you can not use `\left` or `\right`.

If you really want to fake this, you could do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}
$\left(\mkern-1.5mu\vrule width.7pt\mkern2mu
\begin{matrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{matrix}
\mkern2mu\vrule width .7pt\mkern-1.5mu\right)
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.